# Solving an integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an integro-differential equation in the following way

```
NDSolve[y'[x]-NIntegrate[y[t]/(t-x),{t,0,x},y[0]==0],y,{x,0,1}]
```

However, mathematica says

1. t=x is a not valid limit of integration
2. Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by \NDSolve

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The equation inside ``NDSolve`` as written at the moment has typos (there's an initial condition inside ``NIntegrate``, there are missing brackets etc). Please fix those first :-)

A possible solution might be to convert the equation into a 2nd order ODE

Comment: There is exact solution `y[x]=0`, therefore, if $y(x)\ne 0$ at $x>0$, then we need some regularization for this problem.

Comment: @AlexTrunev: If $y(x)\ne 0$ at $x>0$, then the integral $\int_0^x \frac {y(t)} {t-x}\,dt$ diverges.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author of the OP had many days to edit the question and upgrade its level but has not done so.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. The correct equation is NDSolve[y'[x]-NIntegrate[y[t]/(t-x)^a,{t,0,x}],y[0]==0,y,{x,0,1}], with 0<a<1. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you wish to change your question, please edit it instead of adding a comment.  Also, to solve the problem numerically, you must assign a specific value to `a`.